# Difference about pkg-config and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am trying to understand the compile and link process in C++ on Ubuntu.

From what I've learned, `pkg-config` is usually used to extract metadata defined in `.pc` file through `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, then to locate the include and library file needed when compiling and linking.

My question is since we already have `pkg-config`, why do we bother using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ld.so.conf`? Does `pkg-config` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` have different use (I know `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has a higher priority than `ld.so.conf`), or is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` used for the situation when there is no `.pc` file, or is it just this priority thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ld.so.conf` are used to locate shared libraries at run time, when program is started by the loader (`ld.so`). `pkg-config` files instead contain compiler/linker flags (`-I`, `-L`, `-l`, etc.) needed to *build* program that uses particular library (e.g. locate linked shlibs via `-Lpath`).

Also note that many libraries lack `.pc` configs.

Comment: Can I understand it in this way: `ld.so.conf` is only for linking, while `pkg-config` can be used in both compiling and linking to locate and load `include` files and libraries (static or dynamic according to `.pc` configs). So `pkg-config` is more specific.

Comment: @Silentroar No, `ld.so.conf` (and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is only for _running_. `pkg-config` is for compiling and linking.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Silentroar Np, you might want to accept the answer if it answered your question.